# Can I get all custom section from a WebAssembly in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, rust, webassembly

I see there is way i can get a specific custom section with given name.

```
var nameSections = WebAssembly.Module.customSections(module, "sec_name");
```

**Is there any way I can get all the custom sections in a given WebAssembly module?**

Comment: that might depend on if there's a way to get all the custom section names.. idk so I'm just gonna lurk

Answer (score 0):

The [JavaScript interface](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/js-api/#dom-module-customsections) at this time does not offer that. The `customSection` function was discussed and approved [here](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/pull/877). There is currently an opened issue to address the question you asked [here](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/1046). Generally this issue status at this time is that providing such an API would bring too much complexities (not so much about the sections as a list, but about the content of each). That makes sense to me, because the WebAssembly standard is currently in very active development (many post-MVP features are in progress).

That said, it seems that you are left off to parse the binary by yourself. The binary format is documented [here](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/index.html). Basically, after you parse the [magic number and the version](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/modules.html#binary-module) there is a [list of sections](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/modules.html#binary-section): 1 byte ID, one `u32` ([LEB128 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128) with allowed trailing zeroes) for the section's `byte content length` and then are the bytes of the section's content (with that length). After this `header` and the `content` bytes, is the next section, if any, till the end.

The custom sections have an `id` of `0`. The `content` of these sections starts with a [name](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/values.html#binary-name) and after it are the section "user" bytes. This name is a vector of bytes. Each vector has a length (again `u32`) followed by that number of bytes that must be the UTF-8 encoded string.

So the pseudo-code is something like this:

```
parse the magic 
parse the version
loop till there are bytes
  read the section id
  read the section u32 length
  if id = 0 then  
    read the name u32 length
    skip the name bytes
    use the user bytes till the end of the section
  jump to the end of the section
```